# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'controlType') rective form

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I need to put a check box in a rective form so I do this IN MY HMTL

```
    <form [formGroup]="searchForm">

 <mat-form-field appearance="legacy" class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 w-100 p-3">
             
                    <mat-checkbox  class="form-control" tabindex="0" name="flg" formControlName="flg" id="flg" >{{ "APPLICATION.FORMS.CHECKED" | translate }}</mat-checkbox>

                </mat-form-field>
```

in my ts i DO this

```
  searchForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    
    flg:['']
  });
```

in my module I import:

```
 MatInputModule,
   ReactiveFormsModule,
    RicercaRoutingModule,
    MatCheckboxModule
```

I don't know why it gives me this error when I load the page:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'controlType')
```

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are trying to access a "controlType" property, can you include that part in your question?

Comment: @rvrsev no damn